# Squid SSL Bump - getting "unknown issuer" despite having certificate, do I need CA?

Tags: tls, certificates

I am using pfSense on the gateway of my network. I configured Squid and enabled the HTTPS filtering. I created the internal CA and configured Squid to use this internal CA for SSL Bump.

Now the problem is when I try to access any site, this shows a warning message that the certificate is not from a valid issuer, "sec_error_unknown_issuer". Moreover most browsers implement the HTTPS Strict (HSTS) so they won't let the sites open with the non-trusted certificate.

I purchased a server certificate and added this to the CA, but then Squid will not even start.

What should I do? Do I need to add the root certificate of the certifying authority, or I cannot bypass this warning message. For the SSL bumping all Squid needs to do is to behave as a server to the client and as a client to the server.
If it generates a certificate for a particular website on go then it is logically not possible.

My question is how to bypass this warning message on the client machine. I tried adding the certificates to the Firefox lists but this does not help due to HSTS.

Comment: one way to implement this is to add the personal ca certificate to the every client machine but there are many paid firewalls like cyberoem which are capable of doing content filtering but they do not generate any certificate warning how they implement that. do they have their own certification authority. or i am mistaken somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the generated CA certificate to your browser as squid is performing MITM on your https connections.

Comment: but what about https strict. i can not open gmail etc site. chrome will not even let the google to get opened

Comment: hsts is just telling your browser not to try accessing the website in http. Your browser will try directly https but as you will have your SQUID CA trusted, it will work.

Comment: so if i add the ca certificate to the trusted certificates then all sites should open

Comment: Yes exactly, just add the CA certificate to all your client browsers and it should work.

Comment: i am agreed with your comment. but there are many firewalls which do https filtering especially content filtering (like cybereom mime type filtering). do they have their own certification authority or how do they implement it. we dont get any certification error using cyberoem firewall

Comment: If your firewall is doing https filtering at the layer 7 (inspecting the content of the website to block keywords for example), yes you need to add the CA to your clients or use one signed by the company CA. If it's just blocking urls, your firewall can be blocking the server IP or maybe the filtering is done on your company DNS server.

Comment: how to get a signed ca??? do i need to get a server certificate. what should i get signed. i am newbie ..sorry if is ask something irrelevent

Comment: No, nobody will sign you a sub-CA (unless your company has already a PKI), you need to generate one and add it to your client browsers (use openssl for example). Try googling "openssl generate CA".